# Trending algorithm for performance monitoring

Tags: r, time-series, matlab, forecasting, algorithms

### Situation description

I'm trying to implement a prediction (or trending) algorithm for my performance gathering system in order to see when a Linux server's resources will end (for example, free space on a storage or free memory).

The result of the performance gathering process is a graph. So, I need to get on my graph something like this:

[image]

This is an example of RRDtool graph (data collected from Cacti monitoring tool). 
Here are 3 dashed lines that are trend lines for the disk utilization history graph.
That is similar to what I need.

### What I would like to get

The prediction of when the performance will reach some value (e.g. 90%).
Which one of the plenty of prediction (trending) algorithms should I use in my case?

### What I've researched

Holt-Winters algorithm, time series prediction. But I do not know how to use them in this particular case. May be there is other solution?

### Additional information

[30,45,50,10,20,30]-> this is example of disk utilization array (in %).

--------------------> Time, minutes

Critical threshold boundary is 90%.

I need to know when the disk utilization will reach 90% threshold (based on the already collected history of data).

Any examples in Matlab or in R are welcome.

Comment: if your predictions are plain straight lines, you're probably looking for linear regression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression (perhaps with additional increasing weights for later events)

Comment: Implementations details are more important for me than general choosing of method. Thanks for Karoly for the first comment, I got the direction of further research and will answer on my own question soon with real implementation example.

Comment: crible, I think you have your priorities sadly reversed. A superb implementation of a poor method will do you far more harm than a crummy implementation of a good prediction method--unless you don't care at all about the predictions, in which case please just ignore this comment altogether :-).

Comment: @whuber: thanks for your opinion! What do you mean talking "crummy implementation of a good prediction"? Does that mean it will be better to implement something like Holt-Winters algorithm instead of linear regression in this particular case?

Comment: A good example is afforded by the graph you posted to IrishStat's answer: fitting a linear trend to data like that will give exceptionally poor predictions. But please understand I'm not advocating adopting complex, sophisticated models: you have made it clear that simplicity and ease of implementation are virtues for your application. Nevertheless, there is an enormous middle ground of approaches to this problem. Sharing some sample data and improving our understanding of what use you will make of these predictions will help us identify good solutions for you.

Comment: @crible Both Holt-Winters AND and regression are particular cases of an ARMAX model. Data should be allowed to speak to the identification of the model form rather than being restricted to simply providing the basis for parameter estimation.Even if one of these two assumed models was "the best" , unusual data points ( pulses,level shifts,seasonal pulses,local time trends ) play havoc with parameter estimation and the resulting forecasts. Simplicity/speed/cost is important, but the model shouldn't necessarily be too simple, too quick or to cheap as it all depends on opportunity cost!

Comment: The following algorithm may help you.<br>
http://lpenz.org/articles/df0pred-1/<br>
http://lpenz.org/articles/df0pred-2/<br>
http://lpenz.org/articles/df0pred-3/

Answer (score 0):

we run into this problem all the "time" . You have daily data impacted by day-of-week effects ; day-of-the-month effects ; week of the year effects ; Holiday effects ( pre and post ) ; level/step shifts in demand ;  changes in time trends ; changes in parameters over time ; changes in error variance over time and Unusual Values ; and changes in daily patterns over time. AUTOBOX  (a piece of software that I helped design (http://www.autobox.com) will automatically compute the probability that a value will exceed a threshold for any point in the forecast horizon. If you would like to post a link to your data , I will illustrate how this cane done AND not done in Matlab and R. But knowing that it can be done might help you formulate a strategy so as you can get it done ! In this way you can actually see an implementation of your objective.

Comment: @user603 That's always a good reminder to make, thanks.  In this case IrishStat has been clear about his affiliation with Autobox and, over a long time, has consistently been generous with his application of this software on behalf of users who post their data *publicly.*  Sure, it may be good marketing, but (IMHO) it's sufficiently transparent and helpful to fit in with our site, too. If I'm missing the point, or perhaps misinterpreting the FAQ, let's take this up on meta, shall we?

Comment: @whuber: OK, i didn't use the website a lot in the last year so i saw too few of IrishStat's input to judge I guess.

Comment: @whuber my intention as you point out is to detail in a fairly transparent way the possible solution space for a complicated time series problem. Having seen a solution, individual users can always pick and choose their solution objectives and craft/piece-meal their own software solution, albeit short of what I would do BUT a lot cheaper. In this way our craft/good statistical methods gain a foothold on witchcraft and wags.

Comment: How do you think, do I need to implement such complicated methods (I mean like Autobox uses) for my particular goal? It looks like linear regression trend line will show rough but sufficient trend for the current server's load.

Comment: My data is just plain array of collected performance entries (e.g. storage usage in %): [50,50,50,55,55,55,.....]. Size of the array is 60 values. I did a linear regression analysis on a sample data in Excel and got the following results: http://imgur.com/fkIaR

Comment: @crible It would appear to me that your simple trend line is inappropriate as there is a level shift and no trend for the last 40 points.If I were predicting this (in the absence of causal variables!)I would be predicting a continuation of the average of the last 40 values. You might actually post your data.In terms of how to implement this there are a few commercially available solutions,SAS,SPSS,AUTOBOX to name three.In terms of free stuff,you have to be careful as if there is an underlying ARIMA structure/memory structure this complicates the detection of level shifts & time trend changes.

Comment: @crible You need software that detects level shifts AND Local Time Trends.